# Align three images side by side in a div, show one image at a time and hide two

Tags: html, css

Here is my requirement.
I have three images which should be aligned side by side. When I decrease margin-left, all the three images should be hidden one by one in a queue.

[image]
And here comes my actual problem. When I increase margin-left, all the images should go to right hidden part in a queue. But for me they are going down.

My HTML,

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="images">
        <img id="left-img" src="img/trees.png">
        <img id="center-img" src="img/buildings.png">
        <img id="right-img" src="img/interior.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

My CSS,

```
.content
{
   width : 100%;
   overflow : hidden;
}
.images
{
   width : 80%;
   margin-left : auto;
   margin-right : auto;
   height : 550px;
   overflow : hidden;
}
.images-slider img
{
   width: 60%;
   display : inline-block;
   float : left;
}
```

And then When I decrease the margin-left to the left most image, all the images should be aligned like this.

[image]

and similarly, when I increase margin left, all the images should go right like this (which is not happening).

[image]

Instead all the images are going down to the div when I increase the margin left. I used `position : inline;`, `position : inline-block;`, `float: left;`. But nothing is working for me. Where am I going wrong?? Please help me.

Comment: `position` does not take values `inline` or `inline-block` – `display` does … Use `white-space:pre` on the container element, so that the images won’t break into several lines, but stay next to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you can achieve this in the way shown below:

```css
section.images {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section.images figure {
  display: flex;
}

section.images figure img {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

/* Update the left property to change which img is shown */
section.images figure {
  position: relative;
  left: -100px;
}




/* ---------------------------------
    Demo use only
--------------------------------- */

* { margin:0; padding:0 }

img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

img:nth-child(1) { background:gold }
img:nth-child(2) { background:dodgerblue }
img:nth-child(3) { background:orangered }
```

```html
<section class="images">
  <figure>
    <img src="img/trees.png">
    <img src="img/buildings.png">
    <img src="img/interior.png">
  <figure>
</section>
```

Edittable Demo: [http://jsbin.com/fiwajoxixi](http://jsbin.com/fiwajoxixi/2/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much. I saw your demo. That's what I want. I need to work it out. If I get any doubts, I will ask you. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend injecting some jQuery into it to make it easier.

I highly recommend Unslider http://unslider.com